# Integer-valued Blanche Dissection of a Square

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, tiling

[Blanche's Dissection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlanchesDissection.html) divides a square into 7 noncongruent rectangles of the same area.  Seven is the minimum possible.

That solution uses non-integer values.  What is the smallest non-trivial solution where all rectangles have integer sides?

For example, can a $360\times360$ square be divided into different rectangles all with the same area?

EDIT:  mathoverflow has [Tiling a square with rectangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220567/tiling-a-square-with-rectangles).  There and at [Blanche Dissections](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/903043) I outline a solution method.  The method was used to find these 16 non-integer [equidissections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidissection) of a square.

[image: Blanche Dissections]

Comment: A square is a rectangle, is it not? The answer would seem to be 1.

Comment: @Jens Haha, very funny.  I think *nontrivial* dissections are a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Do you know of at least one such dissection? They seem rather difficult to construct.